# starting ignite cluster from command line

Tags: ignite

I am trying to start Ignite cluster from the command line on windows:
this is what I did:

1. Download  Ignite binary version and kept it in C driver.
2. Set Environment Variable IGNITE_HOME to that folder location.
3. in command line I open the directory:
   C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.2.0-bin\bin
4. the from that directory :

   ```
          C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.2.0-bin\bin>sh ignite.sh examples/config/example-ignite.xml
   ```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.spring.IgniteSpringProcessorImpl]
```

what can be the reason for this error?

found the solution for that:
need to run it in bat file and not sh file:

C:\apache-ignite-fabric-2.2.0-bin\bin>ignite.bat examples/config/example-ignite.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows I imagine you should try `ignite.bat`?

ignite.sh might have problems with classpath when run on Windows, that would explain it.